# Power BI DAX - Count number of records if contains string from a reference table

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I write a DAX function to count the number of cells in a column contain a string, from a list of strings in a reference table.

For example, imagine that I have a items table and a reference table:

Items Table:

```
id    items_list
1     hats, jar, shoes
2     Fedora, key, Pens
3     Fedora, jars, Pens
4     baseball cap, Sandals
```

Reference Type Table:

```
id     hat_types    shoe_types
1      hat          shoes
2      fedora       sandals
3      cap
```

I would like to write a DAX function that takes in the strings from the Reference Type table and checks that if the string is contained in the Items table. And if it does, then count the number of rows.

For example:

When looking to see if the strings in the hat_types column are contained in the items_list, I can count 4 rows.

When looking to see if the strings in the shoe_types column are contained in the items_list, I can count 2 rows (first and last row).

How can I do this on Power BI?

Any help you can give is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ShoeCount = 
SUMX(Items,
    IF(
        SUMX(ReferenceType,
            IF(
                LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(Items[items_list]), ReferenceType[shoe_types], ""))
                    < LEN(Items[items_list]),
                1
            )
        ) > 0,
        1
    )
)
```

This iterates through each row in the `Items` table and checks if any of the `shoe_types` are a substring of `items_list`. If so, then you add one to the count.

I test for substring by attempting to substitute any occurrence of the `shoe_types` string with the empty string `""` and checking if that made the whole `items_list` string shorter.

Note: `LOWER`converts the string to all lower case for better matching.

---

The hat counting measure can be done analogously. All you need to do is change `shoe_types` to `hat_types`.

Comment: Thank you Alexis for your answer. I believe the substitute function looks at the whole cell, while I need to check if the the cell **contains** a value from the reference table.

Comment: It checks if it's contained by comparing the length of the string with and without substitution.